# Attempting to load a Vue component and populate it with Ajax json content in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel-5, vuejs2

I am new to Laravel and a complete noob to Vue. I searched many other Laravel/Vue posts but none seemed to be similar enough to get me to a solution. When attempting to load this component on my view I receive the following error

> app.js:32654 [Vue warn]: Property or method "features" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.

Please let me know what I am missing. 
`chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/` shows that Vue is loaded
I would like to load data from an ajax call to my vue component. that can be updated on the fly by event handler

***App.js***

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.component('Example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el : '#app',

});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers : {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
})
```

***Example.vue***

```
<template>
    <div class="container projects-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Example Component</div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <h1>I'm an example component!</h1>    
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item" v-for="feature in features">
                              {{ feature.properties.name }}
                            </li>
                        </ul>                    
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')

        },

    }

</script>
```

***bladefile***

```
<head>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="INMA4kLlG32gfhf4Z3BBGIFxitrVCWzzqgqPfooEj">
// and yes Vue is loaded 
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <example></example>
</div>
...

<script>
Vue.component('example',{
        template: 'Example',

        })  

//returns the JSON listed below
someOtherObject.addListener('click', function(e) {

    $.ajax({
                url:json,
                method:'GET',
                success:function(msg){
                    app.data = JSON.parse(msg);

                    }

                })
})

</script>
```

***JSON***

```
{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               -117.155083,
               33.569672
            ]
         },
         "properties":{
            "heading":null,
            "face":"South",
            "status":"1",
            "name":"MEADOWLARK ",
            "type":"Single Family Home",
            "client_id":"26",
            "client_name":"Pulte Homes",
            "city_name":"French Valley"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               -117.151390,
               33.543981
            ]
         },
         "properties":{
            "heading":null,
            "face":"South",
            "status":"1",
            "name":"Testing Project",
            "type":"Single Family Home",
            "client_id":"83",
            "client_name":"Testing Account",
            "city_name":"Temecula Valley"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               -117.223720,
               33.571522
            ]
         },
         "properties":{
            "heading":null,
            "face":"South",
            "status":"1",
            "name":"Oak Ridge",
            "type":"Single Family Home",
            "client_id":"98",
            "client_name":"Woodside 05S LP",
            "city_name":"Beaumont"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `features` array must be declared either as a prop or part of the component data.

As a prop:

```
<template>
    <div class="container projects-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Example Component</div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <h1>I'm an example component!</h1>    
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item" v-for="feature in features">
                              {{ feature.properties.name }}
                            </li>
                        </ul>                    
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')

        },
        props: ['features']
    }
</script>
```

As component data:

```
<template>
    <div class="container projects-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Example Component</div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <h1>I'm an example component!</h1>    
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item" v-for="feature in features">
                              {{ feature.properties.name }}
                            </li>
                        </ul>                    
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')

        },
        data: function() {
            return {features: []}
        }
    }
</script>
```

If you use a prop, you'll need to bind the prop in the template. If you use component data, you'll need to update the success callback function in the AJAX request to correctly update the data of the *component* rather than the app as a whole.

Also, beware of the reactivity caveats for loading new data, as outlined [in the docs.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)

**EDIT: Full example solution using component data**

Here's a working example using a simplified version of your example component. Note that to do this I used the `ref` attribute so that the component could be addressed directly. Using refs is described [in the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Child-Component-Refs) as an "escape hatch" that should only be used when strictly necessary. A better pattern might be an external store, such as [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/).

```js
Vue.component( "example", {
    template: '<div><h1>Example Component!</h1><ul v-if="features.length"><li v-for="feature in features">{{ feature.name }}</li></ul></div>',
    data: function() {
        return { features : [] }
    }
});

var app = new Vue( { el: '#app' });

//A function to represent the AJAX callback
var doMockAjax = function() {
  var mockData = [{name: 'One'},{name: 'Two'},{name: 'Three'}];
  
  app.$refs.example.features = mockData;
}

document.getElementById('load-data').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  //This simulates the ajax callback by populating the array asynchronously
  setTimeout(doMockAjax,1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <example ref="example"></example>
</div>

<button id="load-data">Load</button>
```

Comment: Thank you,  So if I use the `Component data` how would I target my Vue from the ajax call?

Comment: @happymacarts I have updated my answer with an example. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: ,I have some things sorted out now. I am unsure how to access the Root vue from within the event handlers of, in my case, a google maps object. I am attempting to update the root data as a result of an ajax call inside a google maps event

Comment: One way to do this is to assign your root Vue to a property (or sub-property) of the `window` object so that it's accessible from all your code.

Comment: I did this and it is getting me closer to a solution. So why does [Laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/assets/js/app.js)  Line 20, by default, set the VM object to a CONST ? or am i confusing the Vue object and the Library?

Comment: The scope of the variable/constant is what's in question here. Declaring the VM object as a const is semantically nice, but it's only available in the scope of the code that declared it. To make it accessible everywhere, you need to move it to the window object, where the `const` keyword is meaningless as far as I know.